# How to delete duplicated row in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I try to delete duplicated row in my code with :

```
$post = new posts();
$post->raw('DELETE b1 FROM baroot b1,baroot b2 WHERE b1.post_id = b2.post_id AND b1.id > b2.id');
```

and my model code is :

```
class posts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'baroot';

    protected $fillable = [
        'post_id', 'title', 'modify',
    ];
}
```

I try to delete duplicated with :

```
$post = new posts();
$post->raw('DELETE b1 FROM posts b1,posts b2 WHERE b1.post_id = b2.post_id AND b1.id > b2.id');
```

but any duplicated rows not deleted, I know the sql query is correct but don't work with my laravel code

Comment: The raw function doesn't do anything on the database. It just returns an `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression` object. See https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_raw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of "[Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries)"

> Running A Delete Statement
>
> The delete method should be used to delete records from the database.
>   Like update, the number of rows deleted will be returned:
>
> $deleted = DB::delete('delete from users');

So you have to execute

```
$deleted = DB::delete('DELETE b1 FROM baroot b1,baroot b2 WHERE b1.post_id = b2.post_id AND b1.id > b2.id');
```